# Flutter CachedNetworkImage doesn't leave placeholder

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

So I have this code using the cachednetworkimage function to get an image from firebase storage and to display it once it's available. However, I also want it to display a template when there has been a problem, or if the user didn't upload an image yet. And here I encounter my problem: Eventhough I get an error-message when it hasn't been possible to load the image properly, the cachednetworkimage keeps displaying the loading-animation and doesn't even bother to switch over to the error widget. Is there anything I am missing?

```
     child: CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: _imageUrl,
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 2.0,
          ),
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: imageProvider,
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
      placeholder: (context, url) =>
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
          Icon(Icons.error),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
```

Comment: If the user hasn't uploaded the image yet then are you checking if _imageUrl is null or not?

Comment: Yessss, thank you! I was just starting to work with the getting and uploading of images. I totally forgot that part, however it's really important, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

placeholder overrides errorWidget. replace placeholder with

```
   progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) => LimitedBox(maxHeight: 40,maxWidth: 40, child: CircularProgressIndicator(value: progress.progress,))
```